# PhoneGap App state not saved on pause

Tags: android, cordova, onresume, onpause

When ever I export Android App(using a generated key store from eclipse) application state is not saved when running it. Say I am in 3rd screen, then if I go back to home and click on App drawer and launch it, it starts all over again. But if the app was installed from eclipse itself (through USB debugging) app behaves normally and state is saved.

Weird issue ! What might be causing this ? I checked developer options and activities are not getting killed as well on exit.

Comment: Where are you setting the `LoadUrl` Method?

Comment: @gameower Thats in `onCreate()` method in main activity.

Comment: If you put a `Log.d()` in `onCreate` method, open your app, press home and launch it again, the second time you run the app is onCreate triggered?